# Does any state or other local authorities (eg, city) in the US require to have one's original car registration in the car, or is a scan always enough?

Tags: united-states, driving

I [read](https://clark.com/cars/never-leave-registration-in-glove-box) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20210428225716/https://clark.com/cars/never-leave-registration-in-glove-box/)):

> As far as the car registration goes, the National Insurance Crime Bureau suggests taking a picture of it on your cell phone or keeping a photocopy in your wallet. If you’re pulled over, Atlanta police confirmed to us that an officer will accept a picture or photocopy of your registration, if they even ask for it. Usually, they can verify the information on their computer.

Does any state or other local authorities (e.g., city) in the United States require to have one's original car registration in the car, or does a scan of it always suffice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colorado law says:

> [CRS 42-3-113 (6)](https://codes.findlaw.com/co/title-42-vehicles-and-traffic/co-rev-st-sect-42-3-113.html): The registration card issued for a vehicle required to be registered under this article shall, at all times while the vehicle is being operated upon a highway, be in the possession of the driver or carried in the vehicle and subject to inspection by any peace officer.

Read literally, this requires the original card.  It would probably be at an officer's discretion whether to accept a copy.

By contrast, California has (emphasis mine):

> [Vehicle Code 4454(a)](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displayText.xhtml?lawCode=VEH&division=3.&title=&part=&chapter=1.&article=4.):  Every owner, upon receipt of a registration card, shall maintain the same **or a facsimile copy thereof** with the vehicle for which issued.